# Unable to populate a selectlist with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying to populate a selectlist with some json. I've created a fiddle to help illustrate my scenario.

Though its not quite working you can see I'm simply trying to get the selectlist populated with the 'name' for each style.

```
 var select = $('#newmodel');
    $.each(data.models, function () {
    var thevehicle = data.models.years.styles;
    select.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", thevehicle).text(thevehicle));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YhpHe/4/

Hoping someone can tell me where my thinking is astray.

Comment: Because `years` and `styles` are arrays, so you have to loop over those as well.

Comment: what should be output ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the loop you'll need for your JSON:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.models[i].years.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data.models[i].years[j].styles.length; k++) {
            var option = "<option value='" + data.models[i].years[j].styles[k].name + "'>" + data.models[i].years[j].styles[k].name + "</option>";
            $("#newmodel").append(option);
        }
    }  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/YhpHe/7/

Comment: OMG... thanks a million. I was spending the better part of my afternoon struggling!

Comment: No problem..just remember when you have arrays you'll have to loop through them

Comment: @TJThompson -- Remember to mark it as answered as well if this solved everything.